# How to apply yolo model to directory of images in the same time

Tags: python, yolo

I am new to object detection and I am using a pretrained yolo model from google and I want to apply detection of a single object from the coco dataset(for this case person).
The program is working if I give as input the photo name. But how can this apply to multiple images in the same time? Like for example if you have 100 images in a directory?

The code I use:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import os

image = plt.imread('images/kite.jpg')

classes = None
with open('coco.names', 'r') as f:
    classes = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

Width = image.shape[1]
Height = image.shape[0]

# read pre-trained model and config file
net = cv2.dnn.readNet('yolov3.weights', 'yolov3.cfg')

# create input blob 
# set input blob for the network
net.setInput(cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, 0.00392, (416,416), (0,0,0), True, crop=False))


# run inference through the network
# and gather predictions from output layers
layer_names = net.getLayerNames()
output_layers = [layer_names[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
outs = net.forward(output_layers)

class_ids = []
confidences = []
boxes = []

#create bounding box 
for out in outs:
    for detection in out:
        scores = detection[5:]
        class_id = np.argmax(scores)
        confidence = scores[class_id]
        if confidence > 0.4:
            center_x = int(detection[0] * Width)
            center_y = int(detection[1] * Height)
            w = int(detection[2] * Width)
            h = int(detection[3] * Height)
            x = center_x - w / 2
            y = center_y - h / 2
            class_ids.append(class_id)
            confidences.append(float(confidence))
            boxes.append([x, y, w, h])

indices = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, 0.1, 0.1)

#check if is people detection
for i in indices:
    i = i[0]
    box = boxes[i]
    if class_ids[i]==0:
        label = str(classes[class_id]) 
        cv2.rectangle(image, (round(box[0]),round(box[1])), (round(box[0]+box[2]),round(box[1]+box[3])), (0, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.putText(image, label, (round(box[0])-10,round(box[1])-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0), 2)
        print(label)

cv2.imshow('My window',image)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# ## Create test command
# Creates a test command, stringing together many sub commands using test image folder and output image folder as inputs

# In[1]:

import os

# ### Set input folder, output folder
# - input folder should contain all the .jpg files you want to predict
# - output folder will save your predictions
# - both folders should exist before you run this script

# In[2]:


full_command = ''
skeleton = './darknet detector test cfg/coco.data cfg/yolo.cfg yolo.weights {};cp predictions.png {};'

input_image_path = './predict_these'
output_image_path = './predict_results'

# ### Generate command

# In[4]:

for input_filename in os.listdir(input_image_path):
if '.jpg' in input_filename:
test_full_path = os.path.join(input_image_path, input_filename)
output_filename = 'prediction_' + input_filename
command_partial = skeleton.format(test_full_path, os.path.join(output_image_path, output_filename))
full_command += command_partial

# ### Preview command

# In[5]:

print(full_command)

# ### Write to txt file in same directory as this notebook

# In[6]:

with open('command.txt', 'w') as f:
f.write(full_command)
f.close()

# ### Run terminal command from this notebook (optional)
# - Alternatively can copy and paste from .txt file created above and run in terminal.

# In[ ]:

# os.system(full_command)

# In[ ]:
```

https://danielcorcoranssql.wordpress.com/2018/12/23/yolov3-introduction-and-training-our-own-model/